# Handling push notification and using message in if condition

Tags: ios

I want to have following functionality in my app: When a notification comes the app should use the message in it. From that message app should get the NSDate type string and show a particular view only on that that by using in if condition. Please suggest me how can I do so?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code to retrieve the message you are getting from server

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {


NSLog(@"user info%@",userInfo);  }
```

after getting the messages you can put various condition on your different messages you are getting from server

Comment: Thank for the answer. Please provide more details.

Comment: The above delegate is also a part of the push notification delgates only so you implement this with the rest of the delegates you have implemented already and whenever you will receive any notification this delegate will be fired You can put things like  
 `- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo {

if([userInfo objectForKey:@"Your Key"] isequalToString:@"Your value"])
{
 //Do something on this condition
}
NSLog(@"user info%@",userInfo); 
}`
likewise you data you are getting from your server;